# Changing the default displayAction and playAction labels in tvOS in Top Shelf

Tags: swift, tvos, topshelf

On tvOS if you look at the native Music or Arcade app's top shelf area their "play" action has the label of "Watch Playlist" and "Get" respectively. However I don't see a way to edit these values in my own app as the `TVTopShelfAction` is an `NSObject` with a single value: URL so I would assume this is just for directing the user based on where the button goes and there's no labelling props available for the container class as well (`TVTopShelfCarouselItem`).

The docs say: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvservices/tvtopshelfaction

"When configuring items for a carousel interface, you can specify a custom title and image for the buttons in that interface. If you do not specify a custom title and image, the system chooses default values based on whether you assigned the action object to the playAction or displayAction property of your item."

But it's unclear if that is referring to the `TVTopShelfCarouselItem` which the action becomes a part of and what value I should be changing to customize it. So is this something that's hidden in the TVTopShelfCarouselItem's [namedAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvservices/tvtopshelfcarouselitem/3175238-namedattributes) prop? And if so...which one?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same problem. I've asked Apple about it and they responded that the documentation is wrong. There is currently no way to change the button titles.

There is also no way, that I'm aware of, to display the item's title without the user having to tap for details.

Hopefully in the future this ability is added.
I'd love to know if you find a way.